# type int is not a subtype of type String in type Cast en dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Buenas tardes amigos tengo un problema a la hora de querer obtener una lista de String de mi objeto que tengo, obviamente este json lo recibo desde el servidor hago todo lo necesario cree su modelo y demas aqui les pongo mi codigo:

este es mi modelo Producto:

```
Producto productoFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> str) => Producto.fromJson(str);

String productoToJson(Producto data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

 class Producto {
   List<String> point;
   String name;
   String logo;

   Producto({
      this.point,
      this.name,
      this.logo,
   });

  factory Producto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)  
    {

      var name              = json["name"];
      var logo              = json["logo"];
      var listaPuntos       = json["point"];

      List<String>  listaPuntosList =   listaPuntos.cast<String>();
      return Producto(
          logo: logo,
          name: name,
          point: listaPuntosList
      );

    }


 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "point": List<dynamic>.from(point.map((x) => x)),
    "name": name,
    "logo": logo,
   };
}
```

Todo me esta funcionando bien en este modelo.
Luego desde el producto provider (que es mi CardProvider en realidad) serializo todo ese json q recibi y devuelvo una lista de productos:

```
 class CardProvider {

List<Producto> listaDeProductos;
final preferencias = new SharedPreferencesapp();

Future< List<Producto> >  obtenerCards(BuildContext context) async {

  this.listaDeProductos = new List();
  final String base = NetworkApp.Base;
  final String endPointLogin = NetworkEndPointsApp.obtenerPuntosAcumulados;
   String urlFinal = base + endPointLogin ;

  String userEspecificParametro = preferencias.devolverValor(Constantes.userSpecificToken, 
  "");
  final String parteEndUrl = "?access_token=" + userEspecificParametro;
  urlFinal = urlFinal + parteEndUrl;



  final http.Response respuesta =  await http.get(
    urlFinal
   );

  if(respuesta.statusCode == 200){  ///todo ok

  final Map<String, dynamic> decodedData = json.decode(respuesta.body);

      if(decodedData.containsKey(Constantes.error)){
         if(decodedData[Constantes.error] == Constantes.expired_token){
              //hacer otra cosa fijarse en el android studio
         }else{
          //volverlo a que inicie sesion otra vez
          // Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, routeName)
          }
      } else {

          if(decodedData[Constantes.status]){

                List<dynamic> data = decodedData[Constantes.data];

                for (var elemento in data) {
                          Producto p = productoFromJson(elemento);
                          this.listaDeProductos.add(p);
                }


          }     

     }
  } 

 return this.listaDeProductos; 
 }
```

}

todo bien hasta aqui el problema ya es en mi codigo de pagina osea en mi widget.
 aqui le muestro mi codigo completo del home:

```
Future<List<Producto>> obtenerElBloque( BuildContext contexto){

  CardProvider proveedorCard = new CardProvider();
 return  proveedorCard.obtenerCards(context);
 }

Widget _myPoints(BuildContext contexto){

Producto producto = new Producto();

return new Column(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                        FutureBuilder(
                              future: obtenerElBloque(contexto),
                              builder: ( BuildContext contexto, AsyncSnapshot asyncSnapshot 
                     ) {

                                      if(asyncSnapshot.hasData){

                                   List<Producto> listaObtenida = asyncSnapshot.data;
                                   Producto productoOne = listaObtenida[0]; 
                                   List<String> listaDePuntos =  productoOne.point;
      String losPuntos = listaDePuntos[0]; //aqui es   el problema o el error que me muestra
                                            print(losPuntos);
                                            return Container();
                                      }else {   
                                          if( asyncSnapshot.hasError ){
                                            print(asyncSnapshot.error);
                                            return Container();
                                          }

                                          print("No hay data aun");
                                          return CircularProgressIndicator();

                                      }




                              },
                        ),
                    ],
               );
      }
```

Quizas mostre mucho codigo para una cosa sencilla, pero me tiene mal la verdad no estoy muy metido y me metere mas a fondo de la serializacion y demas json en dart. Muchas gracias.

ACTUALIZADO:
aqui esta el JSON que me retorna desde el servidor:

```
{
"Status": true,
"Message": "Datos Encontrados!!",
"Data": [
    {
        "point": [
            -4
        ],
        "name": "FRIDOLIN CLUB",
        "logo": "http:\/\/www.fridolinclub.com.bo\/user- 
     files\/company\/20190809204351carrucel 1.jpg"
    }
]
}
```

y tambien comentar que puse el sgt codigo como me pidieron:

```
    List<String>  listaPuntosList ;
     try{
     listaPuntosList  =   listaPuntos.cast<String>();
     }catch(e){
        print(e);
     }
```

y el print me responde esto:

```
type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
```

Gracias.

Comment: Perfecto, si me habia olvidao de marcarla gracias @diegoveloper

Comment: sobre el error actual, puedes agregar a tu pregunta el json que retorna, o si es muy largo al menos una parte?  otra cosa, me parece que el error podría ser en esta linea :   List<String>  listaPuntosList =   listaPuntos.cast<String>();   puedes agregar un try /catch ahí ? le agregas un mensaje al capturar la excepción

Comment: ya agregue lo mencionado @diegoveloper, gracias.

Comment: points si puede retornar decimales :). muchas gracias amigo.

Comment: revisa si te sirve mi respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como viste el error es en la conversión de `points` a un listado de Strings, lo correcto sería hacerlo usando `map`.

```dart
  List<String> listaPuntosList =
        (listaPuntos as List).map((item) => item.toString()).toList();
```

Comment: amigo gracias por tu ayuda pero en el try / catch entra por el error  y ahora me da este problema: `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<num>' in type cast` , gracias amigo.

Comment: oh tienes razón, ya actualicé mi código , prueba de nuevo

Comment: todavia me sigue dando error, ahora muestra: 'type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' '

Comment: hmm creo que no era necesario el tryParse, ya actualicé mi código

Comment: Muchas gracias mi amigo, sos un punto crack. jajajaja

Comment: bueno disculpa la palabrota jejeje muchas gracias,